# Angular router navigation issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I got the following folder structure in my angular app. I'm trying to navigate from 
'view-roles' screen to 'update-role' screen on a button click event.

[image]

Following is my button click event.

```
public onButtonClick(data: any): any {

      this.router.navigate(['/admin/update-role']);

  }
```

and I got the below code in my

> admin.module.ts

but it throws 404 error when I click the button. Is there any error in the way I'm using children path?

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'view-roles', component: ViewRolesComponent, data: { breadcrumbs: 'Roles' }, 
    children: [
      { path: './update-role', component: UpdateRoleComponent, data: { breadcrumbs: 'Role' } }
    ]
  }

];
```

Comment: Have you tried a relative path: this.router.navigate(['update-role']) - as you are already on the 'view-roles' route.

Comment: @IanT8 yes. I tried that

Answer (score 0):

Change your children path to be,

```
children: [{ path: 'update-role', component: UpdateRoleComponent, data: { breadcrumbs: 'Role' }]
```

and change the navigate code as follows,

```
 this.router.navigate(['/update-role'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: reproduce it with stackblitz

Comment: try removing the ".."

Answer (score 0):

My routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first',
    component: FirstComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'second',
        component: SecondComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My top-level component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss']
})
export class FirstComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  onClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['second'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```

and my top-level component template:

```
<p (click)="onClick()">
  first works!
</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```